# How to pass a string Arraylist from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Now I tried to use intent extra's to pass and receive through bundle string array list but for some reason the list never passes, when I try to use `get(0)` to retrieve the first string from the list I get a null pointer error, can someone please help me on this?

First Activity (signup activity):

```
 public static final String string_array = "geoquiz.android.bignerdranch.com.string_array";

final ArrayList<String> myStringArray = new ArrayList<>();
myStringArray.add(username.getText().toString());
myStringArray.add(firstName.getText().toString());
myStringArray.add(lastName.getText().toString());

Intent i = new Intent(signUpActivity.this,loginActivity.class);
i.putExtra("string_array", myStringArray);
startActivity(i);
```

Second Activity (login activity):

```
final Bundle stringArrayList = getIntent().getExtras();
final ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<> (); 
stringArray = stringArrayList.getStringArrayList("string_array");

if(username.getText().toString().equals(stringArray.get(0)))
Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "You have successfully logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: That doesn't compile. `stringArray` is declared `final` so you can't reassign it on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `i.putExtra()` use `i.putStringArrayListExtra()`.

Also, add a log entry to make sure the array is populated as you expect.

```
Log.i("myStringArray", myStringArray.toString());
Intent i = new Intent(signUpActivity.this,loginActivity.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("string_array", myStringArray); //modified
startActivity(i);
```

Also, take out `final` in this code:

```
final Bundle stringArrayList = getIntent().getExtras();
//final ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<> (); //no need for this line
ArrayList<String> stringArray = stringArrayList.getStringArrayList("string_array"); //just declare and assign
```

See [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

Comment: Hey I made that change but the null pointer error is still there.

Comment: @WaqasKhan Take a look at the comment from @pbabcdefp, take out `final` when declaring `myStringArray`.

Comment: Yes thank you, arraylist was storing the strings correctly, removing the final solved the problem thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you get wrong the arrayList from the intent in second activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

ArrayList<String> stringArray = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("string_array");
```

Comment: Actually, this is basically the same thing as the current code.  He's just using `getStringArrayList` on the `Bundle` instead of `getStringArrayListExtra` on the `Intent`, which will achieve the same result.